# How to compare hazard ratios between two levels of a categorical variable in Contrast from RMS package

Tags: r, interaction, cox-model, rms

I am performing an interaction spline analysis for age (continuous) and Quartiles of ancestry (categorical). My outcome variable is a survival outcome (incident stroke).

The focus is to compare Q4 to Q1 and allow the hazard ratio to vary across age (continuous variable).
This is my code (using fit.mult.impute since my models are from multiply imputed data).

Am I doing everything right?

Thank you

```
## Model
fit.str <- fit.mult.impute(Surv(years, stroke) ~  rcs(Age,3) + Q + rcs(Age, 3)%ia%Q , fitter = cph,
                          xtrans =imputed_data , data = raw_data)

## Predict
contrast_spline.1 <-contrast(fit.str, list(Q="Quartile 4", Age=22:96), 
                             list(Q="Quartile 1", Age=22:96))

contrast_spline_df <- as.data.frame(contrast_spline.1[c('Age','Contrast','Lower','Upper')])

## PLOT of Hazard Ratios by Age

ggplot() + geom_line(data=contrast_spline_df,aes(x=Age, y=exp(Contrast)), size=1) + 
xlab("Age (in years)") + ylab("HR")+
    geom_ribbon(data=contrast_spline_df,aes(x=Age,ymin=exp(Lower),ymax=exp(Upper)),alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: Note that `contrast` allows you to specify four covariate settings so as to compute double differences and ratios of hazard ratios. That provides an interaction analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you are "doing everything right" depends on what you intended to do. Coding questions per se are off topic here, but here's what I infer your code to have been attempting in terms of statistical analysis so that you can compare against your intentions.

You fit, on multiply imputed data, a model with a minimal (3-knot) restricted cubic spline for `Age`, a categorical predictor `Q`, and an interaction between those two that *omits nonlinear terms* in `Age` (the `%ia%` operator). (You provided no information about how you did the imputation, so that part can't be judged.)

You determined the contrasts and default 95% confidence intervals of the model's linear predictor between the fourth and the first levels of `Q`, for each integer value of `Age` from 22 to 96. Note that the interaction, and thus this contrast, will only involve the linear portion of `Age` even though `Age` itself is modeled to have a non-linear association with outcome.

You plotted the exponentiated linear-predictor contrast (the hazard ratio between the fourth and first levels of `Q`) as a function of `Age`, with confidence bands.

Unless there are coding errors, if that's what you wanted to do you are "doing it right.

A few extra thoughts about maybe doing it better:

First, the nature of the interaction that you modeled might be clearer in your plot if you didn't exponentiate and just displayed the linear predictor  contrast (log hazard ratio). As the `Q` by `Age` interaction only involves the linear part of `Age`, a non-exponentiated plot of the contrasts presumably would be a straight line with a slope equal to the difference in `Age:Q` interaction coefficients between those two levels of `Q`. That type of plot also would make the displayed confidence intervals less skewed. Such simplicity can be hidden by the exponentiation to get hazard ratios. If you want to display hazard ratios with a plot of the linear-predictor contrast, adjust the labeling of the vertical axis to display the corresponding hazard ratios on a non-linear (logarithmic) scale.

Second, your display seems to be using most or all of the range of `Age` values. That can put undue visual weight on the extremes of the `Age` range, where you typically have the least support in the data. You'll note that Harrell's `datadist()` function by default limits display values of a continuous predictor to the 5th and 95th percentiles of a small data set (fewer than 200 observations), or the 10th smallest/largest for a larger data set. Think carefully about whether plotting over such an extreme range makes sense for you and your audience.

Third, this is a pretty minimal survival model that doesn't consider any other predictors. Survival models can suffer from substantial [omitted-variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias) when outcome-associated predictors aren't included in the model. If you have more predictors, use as many as reasonable provided that you don't overfit.